# Chartjs bar chart ranges y-axis -1 to +1 if bars value zero

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart which works in the way I wish excepting that when the data values are zero the chart y-axis is ranged -1 to +1, see image.

[image: Bar chart at zero values]

The code snippet is this

```html
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

@{
 Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Queue Thing</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<h1>Dynamic Queue Details</h1>
<div style="height: 80%">
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  var hub = $.connection.dashHub;

  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   hub.invoke('refresh', false);
  });
  
  hub.on("populateQueues",
   function(queues) {
    updateScreen(queues);
   });
 });

 function updateScreen(q) {
  var labelArray = new Array;
  var dataArray = new Array;
  jQuery.each(q, function (i, val) {
   labelArray.push(val.Name);
   dataArray.push(val.Depth);
  });
  drawMyChart(labelArray, dataArray);
 };

 function drawMyChart(la, da) {
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
    labels: la,
    datasets: [{
     label: '# of Messages',
     data: da,
     borderWidth: 1
    }]
   },
   options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    scaleStepWidth: 100,
    scaleSteps: 9,
    scales: {
     yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
       beginAtZero: true
      }
     }]
    }
   }
  });
  myChart.draw();
 };

 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
</script>
```

How to base the y-axis on zero?

This is chart.js version 2.1.6
Browser is Chrome version 52.0.2743.82 m

Comment: Tim, could you provide a JSFiddle (or something) that works, so that people could check your code with ease? You may need to get rid of some functionality, though. Chart.js has an entry in cdnjs.com (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js/) which can be used in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Here is a link to a simplified (no SignalR) version, but oddly I cannot recreate the problem in JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gopher/2ck3895q/27/

Comment: How often do you re-create the chart, that is how often is `updateScreen` called? Could you provide some data sequences? Also, you can get rid of `myChart.draw();`, since the chart will be drawn at creation time.

Comment: The chart recreates every 2s if the data has changed within the period. Initially the data inspected is 

la
["inputqueue", "inputqueue1", "nottransactionalqueue", "errorqueue", "garbage", "outputqueue"]

da
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

During a test run populating a single bar, la doesn't change,

da[1169, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
da[10003, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
da[86531, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
da[138066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
da[816941, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
da[1000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

as soon as the value exceeds 0 the chart bases Y at zero.

Answer (score 0):

In your options, try setting `suggestedMin: -1` instead of `beginAtZero: true`, like so:

```
 options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: -1,
                }
            }],
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, I would suggest updating the dataset instead of redrawing the chart each time by using the `myChart.update()` function.